# VS-2019 C++ and SFML compiles and runs in Debug mode, but fails in Release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, sfml

I am doing an example from "Beginning C++ Game Programming" by John Horton
Configured VS-2019 to work with SFML and reach the stage of placing two PNG images on the screen and moving them around.
In Debug mode it links and compiles with no errors  the and executes as expected except one thing: the mouse cursor in the game window becomes a ring which keeps and keeps turning as if something is going on in the background. The game's window standard buttons (close, minimize) do not respond to mouseclick.
Close it pressing ESC. The log reads lists all successfully loaded DLL and "The program executed with code 0 (0x0"). No errors

In Release mode it shows the game window empty, no images.
The log reads exactly the same as in Debug mode:  all DLL successfully loaded  and "The program executed with code 0 (0x0"). No errors

However the Windows command line windows shows errors
Failed to loade image "   - !!a0w  Reason: unable to open file
The process exited with code 0
I am not sure I need to copy the whole code here - it is SFML standard inside main function:

```
VideoMode vm(1280, 1024); 
RenderWindow window(vm, "Timber!!!", Style::Default); 
Texture textureBackground;
textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/bg.png");
Sprite spriteBackground;
spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);
spriteBackground.setPosition(0, 0);
while (window.isOpen())
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) { window.close(); }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(spriteBackground);
        window.display();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

tried to use various PNG images - same result. Have no idea what else I can try

Comment: It seems that the texture can't be found in release mode. Are the project settings for debug and release mode the same, with the same working directory when running?

Comment: Recommendation: Build a [mre] (MRE). If you finish making the MRE and didn't figure out how to fix the problem, add the MRE to the question.

Comment: If you are using msvc there should be different dlls and libs for release and debug. If you mix these you can have UB

Comment: The current working directory when you run your code in the IDE should be the same for debug and release. It's set to `$(ProjectDir)` which is a Visual Studio IDE variable that contains the path of the folder that contains the project file. However if you had clicked on the executable in Explorer the folder would be the folder containing the executable so then the relative path `graphics/bg.png` would likely not work. Same goes for running the executable from the folder containing the executable in cmd.exe or powershell

Comment: The paths for debug and release are different. You need to find the path generated in release mode and modify the relative path. What about use absolute path? Will the problem occur?

Comment: Thank you very much to all who responded that quickly. Indeed the problem was in my Release configuration which were set to use Debug versions of SFML DLLs. After correction everything is working.

Comment: One little thing I would like to clear up
========================================
while (window.isOpen())
 {
 if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) { window.close(); }
 }
========================
Results in the cursor turning into rotating circle and the window does not respond to click on the standard window buttons on the right left corner.

Is this supposed to work like this? PS. Sorry, I cannot figure out fow to format code to make it readable